# What's the fastest way to consume enough memory to cause the app to be dumped by the OS?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an app I call memory eater, which is meant to force other applications to be dumped by the os. It does this by consuming lots of memory over time until it is terminated due to memory pressure. In order to consume memory I basically make copies of JPEG representations of data:

```
-(IBAction)didTapStartButton:(id)sender{
    int i = 200;
    while (i>0) {
        NSData* data = [UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.image) mutableCopy] ;
        [self.array addObject:[[data description] mutableCopy]];
        [self.array addObject:data];
        i--;
    }
}
```

This was done entirely with trial and error, and I assume that there is a more straightforward way to consume lots and lots of memory.

Comment: Start The Simpsons Tapped Out ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `malloc()` in a loop.

```
while (1) {
    int *ptr = malloc(4096);
    assert(ptr != NULL);
    *ptr = 0;
}
```

The `*ptr = 0` line is necessary to force the page to be dirty, otherwise you will consume address space instead of memory.  The number 4096 ensures that each iteration through the loop will add exactly one dirty page to the address space, since 4096 is the most common page size.

Comment: That's a bit surprising.  No iOS devices have >1 GB RAM, and I thought there was no swap file.  Am I wrong?

Comment: Please correct me if i am wrong : First there is a pointer that contains the memory address space 0f 4069 using malloc and if no memory found then malloc() will return NULL and in case exit from the program or calling free() to free function. If your program runs a while and keeps malloc()ing and never free()ing when it should, it is said to “leak” memory.

Comment: @whack: That is the gist of a "memory leak".

Comment: @DietrichEpp Can you explain what you mean by "page"? I've never heard that term before, regarding memory management.

Comment: @brimizer: A "page" is the granularity of the MMU, which maps your program's address space (pointers) to the actual locations in physical RAM.  For example, your pointer might be `0x40F00`, but the *page table* might map that to physical address `0x3F9F00`.  This is called *virtual memory* and almost all modern systems have it: the exceptions are typically small embedded systems.  Virtual memory makes it easier to run more than one program at the same time safely, which is why it is so common.